# Nested object creates blank entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

Somehow my create action does not work properly, but the edit action works fine. Something is wrong somewhere in my code and I can't seem to find it. As the title says I create a blank entry even when I fill in my fields.

Roster is nested inside team class, like this.

/teams/id/rosters/id

rosters_controller.rb

```
class RostersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_roster, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :player_roster]
  before_action :team
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @rosters = @team.rosters
  end

  def show
    @players = Player.all
  end

  def new
    @roster = Roster.new
  end

  def edit
    @players = Player.all
  end

  def create
    @roster = @team.rosters.build(params[:roster_params])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @roster.save
        format.html { redirect_to team_rosters_path(@roster.team), notice: 'Roster was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @roster.team }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @roster.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @roster.update(roster_params)
        format.html { redirect_to team_rosters_path(@roster.team), notice: 'Roster was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @roster.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy

    @roster.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to team_rosters_path(@roster.team), notice: 'Roster was successfully deleted.'  }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def team
      @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
    end

    def set_roster
      @roster = Roster.find(params[:id])
    end

    def roster_params
      params.require(:roster).permit(:name, :team_id, :starts_at, :ends_at, :current, :player_tokens, :q)
    end
end
```

rosters form

```
<%= form_for([@team, @roster]) do |f| %>
  <% if @roster.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@roster.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this roster from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @roster.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %><li><%= msg %></li><% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :current %><br>
  <%= f.check_box :current %><br>

  <%= f.label :starts_at %><br>
  <%= f.date_select :starts_at %><br>

  <%= f.label :ends_at %><br>
  <%= f.date_select :ends_at, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %><br>

  <%= f.label :player_tokens, "Players" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :player_tokens, "data-pre" => @roster.players.map(&:attributes).to_json, :id => "player-tokens" %><br>

  <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-warning" %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#player-tokens").tokenInput("/players.json", {
      crossDomain: false,
      prePopulate: $("#roster_player_tokens").data("pre"),
      theme: "facebook",
      propertyToSearch: "gamertag",
      hintText: "Type in a gamertag",
      searchingText: "Searching...",
      tokenLimit: 4,
      preventDuplicates: true
      });
    });
  </script>

<% end %>
```

roster model

```
class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_reader :player_tokens

    has_and_belongs_to_many :players
    has_many :placements

    belongs_to :team, touch: true

    def current_roster?
        current?
    end

    def player_tokens=(ids)
        self.player_ids = ids.split(",")
    end

    def self.total_prize_money
        sum.placements(:prize_money)
    end
end
```

Comment: Kindly share your team's model as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use strong parameters in your `create` method so none of the parameters are passed over to your model.  The model doesn't have any validation for the presence of attributes so it will just create you a blank record.

In your controller, you need to change to use the strong params you already use in the update action.  Change:

```
def create
    @roster = @team.rosters.build(params[:roster_params])
    ...
```

to:

```
def create
    @roster = @team.rosters.build(roster_params)
    ...
```